# How to draw a deployment diagram?

Tags: deployment, uml, diagram

A simple cd player has four buttons: "power" (on/off), "eject" (open/close tray), "play" (if a cd is in the tray: plays the cd or pauses a playing cd) and "stop" (if a cd is in the tray: stops a playing or paused cd). When the player is switched of, the tray closes if it is open. Do not take into account switching the player off in any other way than with the "power" button.

(Question) :Draw a deployment diagram with a cd player, amplifier, Blu-ray player, and television set. The television has also Internet and thus can play YouTube videos.

---

Joey Harwood, I have maybe you would be that kind to help me with it.

[image: an attempt]

Comment: Hi Zana, this sounds like a homework question.  You should make an attempt by yourself and then ask a specific question if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: To help you, without giving a possible answer, in a deployment diagram you can show artifacts and nodes more communication path. So, what list of them can you have ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this clearly looks like someone asking us to do his homework.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an UML modeler to make your diagrams, it would be easier to do for you, and easier to read for us. You have free modelers at your disposal ;-)

Some remarks :

- You did a diagram, that is fine, please next time do not wait for our protests to publish them
- The TV device is not the web server allowing you to access to youtube for instance, it is a web client. So the separate proposal with just the couple CD player -- TV is wrong for me
- It is strange for me to see the CD player and the blueray player connected, what they exchange ?
- Can you explain why youtube is an artifact ?